# How can I update sbt android-plugin's ProGuard version?

Tags: android, scala, sbt, proguard, sbt-android-plugin

I updated my Android SDK's ProGuard from 4.4 to 4.6, but the sbt android-plugin somehow has its own version.  How can I update sbt android-plugin's version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can change the version at android-plugin's build sbt file. lastest version is using proGuard 4.6

https://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin/blob/master/build.sbt

Comment: I assume I have to re-build android-plugin to do this?